# Oracle Data Integrator 11g Reverse Engineer not importing tables

Tags: import, metadata, reverse-engineering, oracle-data-integrator

I am New To ODI 11g, i have to transport data from one Database(Oracle) to another Database(Oracle), for this the table  in source was already imported in the source model, i am trying to setup Target database's meta data in ODI 11g and i have done all the steps right when i try to reverse engineer this new model which i created nothing happens. I am stuck with this problem at work since there is no error so i cannot think of any reason why meta data is not being imported
I would like to clarify this, the target table which i am trying to import is accessed from ODI with the super user

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check that the schema used to connect to the Dataserver where the target table is located actually got the privileges to access the target table?

If not, grant select and insert (and maybe update, delete depending on the IKM you use) on that table.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and resolved it by providing read access to the schema ODI is using to reverse engineer.

As I was using  standalone installation, ODI studio log had the below information:

> [2015-01-17T19:10:21.979+05:30] [] [NOTIFICATION] [] [] [tid: 2374]
>   [ecid: 0000Kfs7s20Fg4WFLzvH8A1KiWkx00000d,0] New data source:
>   [HR/*******@jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/pdb1]

HR schema was the first schema I reverse engineered, and it was being used as default user to read other schemas.

Try checking the agent logs to see what user is being used and provide it the privileges on all other schema's.

Althoug I dont know how to tell ODI to use a particular user to access database while reverse engineering. It would be great if some one gives some insight on it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably on masking of reverse engineering you are missing character: %